# Matlab find function throws size difference error when there is no apparent one

Tags: matlab

My matlab code is attempting to find the indices in a 601 by 1 matrix that correspond to a given value but says the left and right sides have a different number of elements

```
pH_fine = pH(1):0.01:pH(end);
pH_labvals = [7.72,9.87,7.4,7.63,7.06,6.85,8.29,9.37,11.1];
index_labvals = [];
a = find(pH_fine == 8); %This works perfectly

for i = 1:length(pH_labvals)
index_labvals(i) = find(pH_fine == pH_labvals(i)); %This throws an error
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the `find(pH_fine == pH_labvals(i))` on the right side sometimes doesn't find *any* match, and returns an empty result for an index, specifically a 1-by-0 row vector. This doesn't match the size of the left side, which is indexing a 1-by-1 element from your vector `index_labvals`.

You need to check first if the result of [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) is empty, and decide what you will put in the index vector in that case, like a 0 or [`NaN`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html). You will also need to deal with `find` giving you a *vector* of indices if `pH_labvals` has the same value repeated. If you simply want to remove repeated values, you could use [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) like so:

```
pH_labvals = unique(pH_labvals, 'stable');
```

If you're wondering *why* you're getting an empty result from `find`, you should read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/52738) about the perils of floating-point comparison. One possible solution, assuming `pH_labvals` contains non-repeated values with 2 decimal places of precision, is to first [round](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) your `pH_fine` vector to 2 decimal places:

```
pH_fine = round(pH(1):0.01:pH(end), 2);
```

This should allow you to avoid the errors from floating-point comparison.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach is to use `interp1` for table lookup:

```
pH = [1,14]; % Not sure what values you use here, it doesn't matter for the example.
pH_fine = pH(1):0.01:pH(end);
pH_labvals = [7.72,9.87,7.4,7.63,7.06,6.85,8.29,9.37,11.1];

index_labvals = interp1(pH_fine,1:numel(pH_fine),pH_labvals,'nearest')
```

Here, we're finding the nearest index within `pH_fine` that matches each of the values in `pH_labvals`. `1:numel(pH_fine)` are the indices into `pH_fine`.

Note that there's no need for a loop, as `interp1` will lookup all `pH_labvals` at once.